# The Unity console indicates the install succeeded but the game is not found on the mobile device

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, apk, android-developer-api

I tried to build my game on an Android phone, the Redmi Pro 6. On the console it says:

> CommandInvokationFailure: Unable to install APK to device. Please make sure the Android SDK is installed and is properly configured in the Editor. See the Console for more details.
>   C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.1.0f2\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platform-tools\adb.exe -s "4e3919d2" install -r "C:\Users\Godson\trail\colorhunt.apk"
>
> Build completed with a result of 'Succeeded'
>   UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:BuildPlayerAndRun()

However, the game has not installed on the phone.

Comment: Note that the debug indicates the the **build** has succeeded and not the APK installation. Do you have a previous version of this APK on your phone?

Comment: No. I don't have a previous version of apk in that phone

Comment: In that case you can just move the apk file to your phone manually and install it there

Comment: I am going to do that only.  Will it be a problem once I launch my game in play store

Comment: No, I don't think so because you will have to uplad an APK file anyways. Just confirm that you can install it on your phone first.